# How to remove unset break points in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

How should I remove unset break point in Eclipse ?

Even though, I selected **Run -> "Remove all break points"** from menu bar, when I start the server in Debug mode, the debugger stop execution in **ServerEnvironment.class** file.

To continue server start up, I have to manually push "**F8**" to continue the execution. Even though I selected option to remove all break points from menu bar, the break point was not removed.

Is there anything like Caching of break point which I need to clean ? Or other way to remove break point from third party library ?

Comment: How did you add that breakpoint? Is it listed in the _Breakpoints_ view in the _Debug_ perspective?

Comment: Is your break point in an included module? You can place a breakpoint in the projects sourcecode and in the source view of an referenced class. The file Icon has small differents in appearance. I often have this when working on bigger JEE projects with lots of sub modules. So this way it can happen that you have two breakpoints for same line etc.

Comment: You can also try to restart eclipse with -clean flag over the command line. This clears alot of caching stuff etc. Often helps when something went wrong

Comment: No, I have not added that break point. And that break point is not displayed in "Break Point" view in  Debug perspective.

Comment: I tried to Restart eclipse with -clean option.  but it did not work

Comment: @rmertins : I have not included any break point. The class which stops the execution is inside a JAR File. I had attached related source jar when debugger stopped execution pointing to ServerEnvironment.class. So I am able to debug the source code But i am not sure why it stops execution even though I have not created any break point.

Comment: If the break point is in a class which is referenced from a jar and you have the source project of that jar also in the same workspace. Then you can place a breakpoint in this jar classes in two ways. 1. In that jar source project and 2. from the referencing app on the binary classes. So when you are in your web project and you have removed all breakpoints, but it still stop in this jar referenced class, then look in debug view of the source project of the jar if there are breakpoints, too.

Comment: @rmertins : I don't have the same project in my work space But I have related Source JAR File and  Binary JAR File. So the classpath looks like this ...<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/Server-Depedency-support-5.4.0.jar" 
sourcepath="C:/Users/gunjan/Desktop/Server-Depedency-support-5.4.0.jar-sources.jar"/>.

Comment: For solving this issue, I am thinking to create a new JAVA application in my work space with same name and I will copy all the JAVA source code from Source JAR File to that JAVA application. And I will remove Server-Depedency-support-5.4.0.jar dependency from class path by adding this new JAVA app in project dependency. I think. I may solve my problem.

Comment: Good luck seems to be user Problem

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that there is an uncaught Exception in that class, which Eclipse suspends on per default.

Open preferences and go to `Java`=>`Debug`. In the `Suspend Execution` section you can select on which action the debugger suspends per default. Try removing one or all of them.